# Noticeable difference between i7 920 and 940 processors in real-life use?

Tags: performance, cpu, hardware-rec, intel-core-i7

I'm just looking for a simple answer, such as **"it's WAY quicker, GET IT"** or **"don't bother, not worth the extra cash"**.

The price difference between the 920 and 940 i7 chips is massive so I want to make sure I get the right CPU first time round and not later wish I spent the extra cash for a big performance boost when I had the chance.

So, my question is has anyone had experience with computers containing both processors and have experienced a noticeable different between the two?  What would you recommend considering the difference in costs - 920 or 940 - and why?

I excluded the 960 as I don't tend to see this CPU as an option with the mainstream computer manufacturers.  Free free to comment on the 960 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"don't bother, not worth the extra cash".

If coming off of anything less than two years old, you will notice that when you start up and run things, it will generally be quicker. Anything older than two years and everything will be noticeably quicker.

Between the 920 - 940, I cannot say that you will see any big performance gains. I use many CPUs on a daily basis, and for .5GHZ (within same generations) you really cannot tell many differences

Answer (score 2):

The general thought I've seen is "not worth the extra cash". I personally run a Core i7 920

Look at [these benchmarks from Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/2009-desktop-cpu-charts/benchmarks,60.html) for some examples on the performance difference between the processors. For the most part, they're very slight differences, and in real-world usage, you'll barely notice the speed difference.

Answer (score 1):

What software do you use that would benefit in the $300 price difference?  If you are a speed junkie/bleeding edge you would of just jumped and got the 975 so I can't see the large price jump being worth it.  That $300 could go to a nice SSD which would be a way better investment IMO.

Answer (score 1):

IT'S ABOUT 9% QUICKER, GET IT! IT'S ONLY 9% QUICKER, FORGET IT!

That's what you looking for, mate?

Answer (score 0):

Theres a pretty good [article on TechSpot](http://www.techspot.com/review/124-intel-core-i7-920-940-965/) comparing these and one other model.